# R Shiny Reactive: Object not found when table is imported from a txt file

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

The following script runs fine if I define the data table within the script by "data.table(...)".
For larger data sets it is more comfortable to import data from a text file using "read.table(...)".

Unfortunately the script does not run properly when the data is imported from a text file. The error message is: "Warning: Error in grepl: object 'material' not found"

The column "material" cannot be identified in this case. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

```
#This is the content of example_data.txt (sep. by tabulator):
#id londd   latdd   material    application name    color
#1  20  60  stone   a   1   red
#2  38  56  water,sand  b   2   green
#3  96  30  sand    c   3   blue
#4  32  31  wood    d   4   yellow

# Filtermap
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

#mydat <- data.table( id=c(1,2,3,4),
#                 londd=c(20, 38, 96, 32),
#                 latdd=c(60, 56, 30, 31),
#                 material=c("stone", "water,sand", "sand", "wood"),
#                 application=c("a","b","c","d"))

mydat <- read.table("example_data.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t",
encoding="UTF-8")

#Set up ui
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(h5("", width=2),
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId="MatFlag",label=h4("Material"), 
               choices=setNames(object=c("stone","water","sand", "wood"),
               nm=c("stone", "water", "sand", "wood")),
           ),
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId="AppFlag",label=h4("Application"), 
               choices=setNames(object=c("a","b","c","d"),
               nm=c("a","b","c","d")),
           ),
           position="left"),

#App mainPanel content and styles
mainPanel(fluidRow(leafletOutput(outputId="lmap")))
))

#Set up server
server <- function(input, output){
#Build leaflet map
lmap <- leaflet(data=mydat)%>%
addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", 
                 options =providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
fitBounds(~min(londd), ~min(latdd), ~max(londd), ~max(latdd))

#Filter data
datFilt <- reactive({
MatSearch <- paste0(c('xxx',input$MatFlag),collapse = "|")
MatSearch <- gsub(",","|",MatSearch)
mydat[grepl(MatSearch,material) & application %in% input$AppFlag]
})

#Add markers based on selected flags
observe({
  if(nrow(datFilt())==0) {
      print("Nothing selected")
      leafletProxy("lmap") %>%
      clearMarkerClusters()
  } else { 
      print("Something Selected")
      leafletProxy("lmap", data=datFilt()) %>% 
      clearMarkerClusters() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng=~londd, lat=~latdd,
                     clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(), weight=3,
                     color="#33CC33", opacity=1, fillColor="#FF9900", 
                     fillOpacity=0.8)
  }
})

output$lmap <- renderLeaflet(lmap)
}

#Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: For starters check your `read.table` in R console. The column names should be messed up.

Comment: I don´t think the column names are messed up. If I view the table in R it looks exactly the same in both cases. 
Can you give me a hint what you think is messed up?

Comment: So if you execute the `read.table` command and then do `str(mydat)` all the columns are there, but once you start the app, column material is not found??

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if I do `str(mydat)` it says data.frame and not data.table. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Try putting `material` and `application` in `""` when you use it in the server.

Comment: In this case the script runs without any error message, but no data points appear on the map...